# Regex for python request

Tags: python-3.x, regex, escaping

Hi I'm looking for a solution to create a function that returns a list of dictionaries whith the next structure

*Example*:

```
example_dict = {"host":"146.204.224.152", 
               "user_name":"feest6811", 
               "time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700",
               "request":"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"}
```

The data looks like this:

```
146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554 
156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701
*Keeps going more entries...*
```

My function looks like this:

```
import re
def logs():
    with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
    pattern="""
(?P<host>.[\d.]*\s?)         #host
(?P<user_name>[\s\w-]*\s?)    #user_name
(?P<time>[\w\/\:\.\[\s-]*[\]\s])           #time
(?P<request>[\w\/\"\s.]*"?)     #request"""
    group=[]
    for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE):
        group.append(item.groupdict())
    return group    
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

And retunrs something like this:

```
[{'host': '146.204.224.152 ',
  'user_name': '- feest6811 ',
  'time': '[21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700]',
  'request': ' "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622\n197.109.77.178 '},
 {'host': '- ',
  'user_name': 'kertzmann3129 ',
  'time': '[21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700]',
  'request': ' "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web'},
 {'host': '+',
  'user_name': 'services',
  'time': ' ',
  'request': 'HTTP/2.0" 203 26554\n156.127.178.177 '}]
```

What can I change in order to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
    pattern="""
    (?P<host>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})\s-\s  #host (IPv4 only)
    (?P<user_name>[\s\w-]*?)\s?             #user_name
    \[(?P<time>[\w\/\:\.\s-]*)\]\s?         #time
    "(?P<request>.*?)"\s?                   #request
    (?P<code>\d{3})\s?                      #response code
    (?P<bytes>\d+)\s?                       #bytes sent or received
    """
```

https://regex101.com/r/l7N52c/1

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion @Alexander Mashin. It worked as I wish.

Comment: This pattern gives me the desired result however it adds an extra space at the end of the user_name, when I tried to remove that, it messes up with other values. Any way to remove it without changing other values.

pattern="""
        (?P<host>[\d.]+)(?:\s*-\s*)
        (?P<user_name>[\s\w-]*)
        \[(?P<time>[\w\/\:\.\s-]*)\]\s?
        (?P<request>\".*?\")
        """

Answer (score 0):

You could try following regex.

```
(?P<host>[\d.]+)(?:\s*-\s*)(?P<user_name>\w+)(?:\s*\[)(?P<time>.*?)(?:\])(?:\s*)(?P<request>\".*?\")
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3dZhMT/1)

Comment: This pattern gives me the desired result however it adds an extra space at the end of the user_name, when I tried to remove that, it messes up with other values. 

pattern="""
        (?P<host>[\d.]+)(?:\s*-\s*)
        (?P<user_name>[\s\w-]*)
        \[(?P<time>[\w\/\:\.\s-]*)\]\s?
        (?P<request>\".*?\")
        """

Comment: Easy. Add a question mark to make the user name non-greedy as in the edited reply.